# Adding up a row of percentages in excel

Tags: excel, list, sum, average, calculated-columns

Hi I am trying to add up a list to get a percentage calculation. and it comes out different. im sure it is my lack of understanding what percentage is doing but normally it seems to work fine but not today :)

Is there a way of getting the average to not get to 0.047 to do the same as the blue to get to 0.0509?
I have used =AVERAGEIF(E11:E50,"<>0") before and it seemed to work. but it makes it worse. I get 0.0574  further from my target 0.0509.

Help me get there please ( i wont have the blue columns so i cant use thme. I just broke it out to see what was going on)

[image]

Comment: The average you are doing is the average of the average.  To get what you want you will need to do the division of the sums: `=SUM(G13:G52)/SUM(I11:I50)`

Comment: Hi. tried googling in a different way and it seems the base number is the issue. I wont have the G and I so i cant use them in formula. is there a way to break down the percentage in E to then add up?

Comment: No, unless you know the numbers that created the percentage, you will never be able to match.  You need to know at least two of the three numbers you show in each row.

Comment: " further from my target 0.0509."  --> err.. in ur H10 & I10 formula.. u used different range for calculation.. ( 1 is row 13 to 53 , another is  11 to 50 ) .. it should be the same row range .. right?

Comment: Just to note. I ended up using a base number column then doing the percentage calculation on that to get round the problem. thank you for your help